# Finding Graph Partitions with Minimum Edges Crossing Partitions

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory

I have recently been working on a few algorithms and have gotten stuck on the following problem:

Given an undirected unweighted possibly disconnected graph G(V, E) find k partitions of G such that each partition has the same number of vertices (assume the total number of vertices is a multiple of k) and that there is a minimum number of edges in G that connect vertices in different partitions.

I am not looking for a polynomial time algorithm for this problem (as it is probably NP-Hard anyway), but rather an algorithm that will find a solution for 150 vertices and 1200 edges in under 24 hours. While any good approximation algorithms would be much appreciated as well, I would prefer an exact solution.

I kept the problem as simple as possible, however a general solution for a directed weighted graph would be nice as well.

Thanks for any and all help!

Update: I just did some more research and realized this can be reinterpreted as a modified connectivity problem. Maybe there is a solution along that line of thinking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed an NP-hard problem. If you're handy with convex optimization or can learn, my instinct is to formulate this problem as an [exact cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_cover) [integer program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming) with many variables (one per subset of |V|/k vertices) and then actually solve that program by [generating columns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Column_generation) with an integer program solver to find partitions with many interior edges. The subproblem formulation will look like

```
maximize sum_{vertices v} w_v x_v + sum_{edges uv} y_{uv}
subject to
sum_{vertices v} x_v = |V|/k
y_{uv} <= x_u for all edges uv
y_{uv} <= x_v for all edges uv
x_v in {0, 1} for all vertices v
y_{uv} in {0, 1} for all edges uv
```

where `w_v` are weights determined by the dual solution to the master problem, intuitively understood as how urgently a particular vertex needs coverage.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to use clustering algorithms. You are not going to get the optimal solution, but a quick semi-optimal solution.

You could approach this in various ways. For example, you could use biclustering. Or you could do principle component analysis, pick a few components and run a modified k-means algorithm.